# Problems using apache 2.2 as a Reverse Proxy for Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, team-foundation-server, iis-8.5

I'm using an Apache 2.2 in order to access a Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 configured to use NTML.

My configuration for this purpose is the following:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /tfs/ http://tfs2015.mdlp.es:8080/tfs/
ProxyPassReverse /tfs/ http://tfs2015.mdlp.es/tfs/
```

Apparently this configuration works pretty fine when there is only one user. When a seccond user connects it appears as the user previously logged.

I guess this is happening due to the connection pool apache maintains against the backend server, and it is like TFS once the user on this keepalive connection is authenticated relies on the first requests to be aware about the user. As far as apache will forward all requests to the already created pool, this will mix user sessions in the same keep alive connection.

At this point I've tried to use the disablereuse=On directive on ProxyPass in order to avoid the use of connection pooling, but this way the NTLM authentication is not working.

Just wondering if anyone was able to solve this problem, which perhaps is not related 100% to Team Foundation but to IIS.

EDIT:

As far as I have an apache 2.0 installed on the same Reverse Proxies I've tried to configure them the same way, and it works properly. So there is a way to limit the proxypass features on apache 2.2 to behave like apache 2.0?

Comment: I have the same problem with azure devops server, did you find any solution?